# Organizing python project with setting environment

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I develop Python tools. Each tool is part of a programming project, with source files and scripts to launch a program. Here the language is Python but could be any other.

```
src/
  package1/
    module1.py
  package2/
    module2.py
scripts/
  program1.py  # parses arguments; uses modules; starts workflow.
  program2.py  
  pylauncher.sh  # sets environment; deals with output; calls any specified python script.
```

Each Python script takes the user's input, parses the arguments provided, and starts a routine using the relevant Python modules. In the end the user just has to call the script this way:

```
$ cd path/scripts
$ python program1.py arg1 arg2
```

or, depending on the interpreter version,

```
$ cd path/scripts
$ path/to/the/right/python program1.py arg1 arg2
```

Currently I also have a bash script, pylauncher.sh, that I use to set Python path, Python libraries, redirecting of the input into a log, and such. So the user doesn't have to specify all this and has to launch the command:

```
$ cd path/scripts
$ ./pylauncher program1.py
```

This is convenient as it hides environment stuff from the user. But it seems to me that maybe the user should not be bothered with calling a launcher. So I am thinking of getting rid of the python scripts program{1,2}.py and renaming the pylauncher.sh into program{1,2}.sh. In doing so, the routine that was used in the former program{1,2}.py would be transferred into a module's main function, or simply moved there.

The project structure would look like:

```
src/
  package1/
    module1.py
    program1.py  # parses arguments; use python modules; starts the program workflow.
  package2/
    module2.py
    program2.py
scripts/
  program1.sh  # sources set_environment.sh; calls program1.py
  program2.sh  # sources set_environment.sh; calls program2.py
  set_environment.sh
```

Or letting the program{1,2}.py in the scripts folder:

```
src/
  package1/
    module1.py
  package2/
    module2.py
scripts/
  program1.py  # parses arguments; starts the program workflow.
  program1.sh  # sources set_environment.sh; calls program1.py
  program2.py
  program2.sh  # sources set_environment.sh; calls program2.py
  set_environment.sh
```

The user would in the end have to use the following command:

```
$ cd path/scripts
$ ./program1.sh
```

So I am currently using the first solution with the pylauncher bash script, and I am thinking about changing to the second solution. However I would like to know about other software devs' take, habits, practices. How would you do that? Do you see more convenient way, for the user, for the developer, if possible avoiding redundancies? Any advice and critics are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered packaging these tools as single file executables?

Here's a very basic example of what I mean using pyinstaller, I'm on a linux system, but the tool is cross platform and looks well documented.

requirements (python headers for building and PIP to install the package)

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip
sudo pip install pyinstaller
```

file to build

```
kalvatn@workstation|/tmp/python-executable » cat hello.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'hello world'
```

usage (the -F flag instructs pyinstaller to create a single file executable)

```
kalvatn@workstation|/tmp/python-executable » pyinstaller -F hello.py
kalvatn@workstation|/tmp/python-executable » ./dist/hello
hello world
```

doc

- https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller
- https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have not considered using pyinstaller yet. It may be interesting for a Python exclusive project. For now I am looking for a general way of organizing projects.

Comment: @kaligne oh, I thought this was a python exclusive project, I think you might want to clarify some points in the original question to get better answers :)

Comment: yes I am sorry it was not that clear after all. Should I remove the python tag then?

Comment: if it's not related to python, then why should it be tagged with python? :)

I think I would rewrite the entire post, as it is full of python related folder structure that detracts from the apparently more abstract problem that you are wondering about. 
I answered with the pyinstaller suggestion as it seems the main problem is how to organize and manage scripts to execute python programs, to which I would still suggest some sort of packaging by the way

Comment: Ill keep this post here then. Maybe more interesting ways of solving it pop up later :) If I understood correctly, pyinstaller takes care of the python version and the modules used by the program. So I could use pyinstaller on a linux machine, then execute the resulting binary on any (tested) linux machine, regardless of the python version and libraries the program is linked to. Correct?

Comment: that's the idea at least.. I guess you'll have to read up on pyinstaller's capabilities. But pyinstaller is just an example, my point is that if you're developing what looks like a 'shared toolbox', you'd like to make this as simple and transparent for people to use; not have to worry about the python path or other system environment variables etc.. Of course this also very much depends on who your end-users are and the scale of this operation. If your current solution is working fine, then why fix it? :)

Comment: other alternative distribution methods https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver , https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm